# How to install packages with no internet / Update to 18.04 - no WiFi anymore

Tags: networking, kernel

After the update my WiFi connection is broken. I do not have the option to use a wired connection on this machine.
I was familiar with the fact that I had to recompile the WiFi driver (rtl8188eu) after every kernel update.
The update to 18.04 decided that the ELF libraries and headers are obsolete and not needed (due to my opinion a bad decision on an ELF system) and I cannot build the module anymore.

My configuration:
Kernel 4.15.0-39-lowlatency, includes in place, GCC Version 7.3.0, GNU Make version 4.1

I have a second machine available with which I can download the packages. Can anyone tell me what to get and how to install it?
apt-get will not work due to the missing network connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have access to internet, you can still dowload the packages from https://packages.ubuntu.com/ to usb stick and install them with `sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was what I was searching for but it didn't do the trick. The build raises a type error.

I had a look with lsusb and I found a Realtek RTL8188 WiFi controller

Answer (score 0):

Solved for now
I replaced the TP-Link adapter with the RTL chip by an Edimax one

Realtek has a Liux driver download for Linux on their site.
When I sometime find the time I'll give it a try.
The Realtek drivers amongst the packages didn't work.